# Rails Active Record "too few arguments" on create/save call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a fairly simple action in my controller, as shown below:

```
def create
  @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)

  if @quote.save
    render :json => @quote,
           :status => :created,
           :location => @quote
  else
    render :json => @quote.errors,
           :status => :unprocessable_entity 
  end
end
```

I have this same snippet in other areas of my application and this problem does not occur.

I'm sending a POST request to `/api/v1/quotes` with the JSON and all the proper parameters are whitelisted.

But i'm getting this error: `too few arguments` on the `@quote.save` line.

Why is this?

Comment: Publish what you are receiving in quote_params.

Comment: `params.require(:quote).permit(:field1, :field2, :field3, :association_attributes => [:id, :field1, :field2, :field3])`

Comment: You have put the code inside 'quote_params' method in above comment. Publish the parameters which your receiving via form. You can check that in log. Params are not being passed correctly, that's why its giving argument error.

Comment: It's my comment inside of `def quote_params` `end`

Comment: Yes, i know. But its not sufficient to solve the issue. You will need to publish what params you are getting via form so that it can be debug why its giving argument error.